# RevealTrans Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, object

```
marco.getDiv().filters[0].Apply();
marco.getDiv().filters[0].Play();
```

marco es un objeto
`getDiv()` retorna `this.getDiv()`;

Me gustaría saber qué hacen esas líneas de código porque no encuentro solución en otras páginas de Internet.

La consola devuelve este error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: Hola Nico, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Has de explicar qué problemas tienes para entender ese codigo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve la consola? Es la mejor forma de debuggear y saber qué está haciendo JS en cada paso.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser codigo relacionado con animaciones, en cuestion es **[RevealTrans](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30011&seqNum=4)**, pero es bastante viejo por lo que veo, junio de **2002**.

[Aqui](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3470401/RevealTrans-Filter.htm) tienes un poco mas de codigo parecido al tuyo.

Comment: Gracias por los enlaces!!